# can I use invoke to abstract class method

Tags: c#, generics

As below code i just want to know can I use Invoke() for abstract class

```
public abstract class genericDefine
{
    public void Foo<T>(T item)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(typeof(T).Name);
    }
}

var bar = typeof(Bar);
var fooMethod = typeof(genericDefine).GetMethod("Foo");
var fooOfBarMethod = fooMethod.MakeGenericMethod(new[] { bar });
fooOfBarMethod.Invoke(new genericDefine(), new object[] { new Bar() });
```

I also tried for use Derived class object but it wont work for me....!

Comment: Simple answer: NO. (Un?)fortunately I cannot post such a short answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to invoke the `MethodInfo` without passing in an instance of the object you need to have that method defined as `static`. So if your method was defined as such it does work. Otherwise you need to have an subclass instance of the abstract base class.

```
 public abstract class AbstractClass
 {
     public static void Foo<T>(T item)
     {
         Console.WriteLine(typeof(T).Name + ": " + item);
     }
 }
```

But then why have the class be `abstract`?

1. You either need an instance from a class that inherits the `abstract` class
2. Or, you need to make the method `static` -- which defeats the purpose of `abstract` classes

[Here is the .NET fiddle.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/kIaQMo)

Answer (score 4):

You either have to make the method static, or pass in an instance to call the method on. You can't call an instance method without actually having an instance (and you can't instantiate an abstract class).

So either this (using an instance):

```
public class genericDefineInstance : genericDefine
{ }


...
fooOfBarMethod.Invoke(new genericDefineInstance(), new object[] { new Bar() });
```

Or (using an static method):

```
public static void Foo<T>(T item)
{
    Console.WriteLine(typeof(T).Name);
}

...
fooOfBarMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { new Bar() });
```

Answer (score 0):

No you can not. To call your method, you still need an instance of the class, and you can't create an instance of an abstract class.